# How do I make a try-except statement catch an error more than once?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, valueerror

I am currently making a calculator application with a menu. When an invalid input (eg. String) is entered, the `ValueError` exception is thrown.

I have a `try-except` block to catch the exception. However, it will only catch it one time. If I do the exact same input after, the `ValueError` exception is thrown and it's not caught.

#### Code I have

##### Original

```
def get_user_choice():
    try:
        user_choice = int(input("Choice: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nERROR: Please enter a valid integer value. Retrying...\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        show_menu()
        user_choice = int(input("Choice: "))
        pass
```

##### Modified

If I put the `get_user_choice()` function in the `except` instead of asking for `user_choice`, it throws an `UnboundLocalError`.

```
try:
        user_choice = int(input("Choice: "))
except (ValueError, UnboundLocalError):
        print("\nERROR: Please enter a valid integer value. Retrying...\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        show_menu()
        get_user_choice()
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the try-except into a loop. It will continue to run until a valid value is entered and it returns.

```py
def get_user_choice():
    while True:
        try:
            user_choice = int(input("Choice: "))
            return user_choice
        except ValueError:
            print("\nERROR: Please enter a valid integer value. Retrying...\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            show_menu()

user_input = get_user_choice()
```

You could also use recursion:

```py
def get_user_choice():
    try:
        return int(input("Choice: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nERROR: Please enter a valid integer value. Retrying...\n")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        show_menu()
        return get_user_choice()
```

The problem in your modified code is that you are not returning the value.